# AFNetworking: Using AFJSONRequestOperation with UTF8 file

Tags: json, utf-8, character-encoding, afnetworking

I'm trying to use AFNetworking for getting JSON asynchronously.

I have a json file encoding in UTF8 and AFJSONRequestOperation return me dictionnary with UTF8 code:

```
éphémère   -->   \U00c3\U00a9ph\U00c3\U00a9m\U00c3\U00a8re
```

Is there a way to have UTF8 works good with AFJSONRequestOperation?

There is a seconde issue using AFJSONRequestOperation: he can't read UTF8 file with BOM.

Here is my code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                         {

                                             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

                                         }];
    [operation start];
```

Before that I was using JSONKit and it works great (charset + BOM)! But I need to make an asynchronous call.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `\U` is invalid JSON. See the syntax at http://json.org/

Comment: My JSON is {"test" : "éphémère"}. And the NSLog display this: JSON: {
    test = "\U00c3\U00a9ph\U00c3\U00a9m\U00c3\U00a8re";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a NSLog's problem, your JSON is valid, you can retrieve a key's value in it and see its valid characters.

I use this code to make my response JSON more readable:

```
-(NSString*)stringByReplacingUnicodePoint:(id)jsonObj
{
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObj options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}

-(void)networkResponse:(id)JSON
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [self stringByReplacingUnicodePoint: JSON]);
}
```